# get all text variations from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I get in javascript all variations of string with structure like:

```
"{Here|This|This Really} is {example|Instance |Illustration }"
```

example:

```
Here is example

Here is Instance

This is example

...
```

Comment: Make the question more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use `split('|')` for both of the options and loop through them to get all the combinations:

```js
var option1 = "Here|This|This Really";
var option2 = "example|Instance |Illustration";
var combination = [];
option1.split('|').forEach((str1) => {
  option2.split('|').forEach((str2) => {
     combination.push(str1 + ' is ' +str2);
  });
});

console.log(combination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern Javascript:

```js
const s = "{Here|This|This Really} is {example|Instance |Illustration }"
const [a, b, c] = s.match(/\{(.+)\}(.+)\{(.+)\}/).slice(1),
    combine = [].concat(...a.split('|').map(d => [...c.split('|').map(e => `${d}${b}${e}`)]));
console.log(combine);
```

Comment: what if the amount of the parameters dynamic ?

Comment: Then its more complicated